# std::async,std::promise and std::packaged_task will block the main thread.What is the meaning of them?

Tags: c++

The std::async blocks my UI thread as below, which is not what I expected.
So, What is the meaning of std::async, std::promise and std::packaged_task?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

void func_cb()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i ) {
        std::cout << "do something..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 1000 ) );
    }
}

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    std::async( std::launch::async, func_cb );
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::async` returns a `std::future` which the code doesn't save. The destructor of the `std::future` blocks the thread until the value is available.

The code probably needs to save the return value of `std::async` or use a detached `std::thread` instead.

Comment: std::future<void> f_res = std::async( std::launch::async, func_cb );
Like this? But I have no need to use the return object.

Comment: @Allen If you don't want the return value don't use `std::async`, use a detached `std::thread`.

Comment: So, I don’t know What the meaning of std::async, std::promise and std::packaged_task  is.

Comment: @Allen Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async